# boost::exists for symlinks do not dereference

Tags: c++, boost

In `boost::filesystem`, the `path` class always tries to dereference symlinks. A lot of the API is catered towards trying to make symlinks seem invisible. I'm guessing a lot of their syscalls underneath are `stat` related instead of `lstat` related. This is problematic for me, as I'm trying to get the symlink itself.

For example, doing `fs::exists("some_symlink")` because, although `some_symlink` exists, its referent does not exist. I want this to give me back true, and in the older versions of boost it supports it: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/filesystem/doc/operations.htm#symbolic_link_exists

However, now it doesnt. Is there any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `boost::filesystem::symlink_status` to get a `file_status`, and then check its `type()`.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    auto a = boost::filesystem::symlink_status("a_symlink");
    auto b = boost::filesystem::symlink_status("main.cpp");
    auto c = boost::filesystem::symlink_status("not_existing");
    auto d = boost::filesystem::symlink_status("a_broken_symlink");
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << (a.type() == boost::filesystem::file_not_found) << " " 
        << (b.type() == boost::filesystem::file_not_found) << " "
        << (c.type() == boost::filesystem::file_not_found) << " "
        << (d.type() == boost::filesystem::file_not_found) << "\n";
}
```

Execution:

```
$ touch f 
$ ln -s main.cpp a_symlink
$ ln -s f a_broken_symlink
$ rm f 
$ ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 2001 2000   1 Jun  3 23:33 a_broken_symlink -> f
lrwxrwxrwx 1 2001 2000   8 Jun  3 23:33 a_symlink -> main.cpp
-rw-rw-rw- 1 2001 2000 637 Jun  3 23:33 main.cpp
$ g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system main.cpp && ./a.out
false false true false
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26186dbd7a3f9b71)</kbd>